Endpoints in Program.cs work but not in Controller
I have a small .NET Core test program, running in a Debian CT on Proxmox at 192.168.1.200:5000. When I test the API with Postman, the /test endpoint works. On the same machine as well as on other machines in the same network. But when I test /api/greet from my controller, I get an error http 404. Any idea why?
Here the successfull /test and the unsuccessfull /api/greet:
/test 200 OK
/api/greet 404 Not Found
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapGet("/test", () => "Test route reached");
app.Run();

Controller.cs:
namespace HelloWorldApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("greet")]
        public IActionResult GetGreeting()
        {
            return Ok("Hello World");
        }
    }
}

I tried other ports, I deleted the whole code and wrote it again, I even used code from an old project that worked. Even if I put a Console.WriteLine("test") into the Constructor of the Controller, it doesn't get printed, so somehow the Controller does not get initialized?

The route of your controller method as defined by your attributes will be /api/greet - but in your screenshot illustrating the 404 error, you used /api/HelloWorld/greet ... almost seems like you're somehow mixing the attribute-based routing, and the standard mapping-based routing from earlier versions here....

Sorry my fault, the code is the last version of the original, the Tests are base on changed code that another user suggested. It was late and I didn't think that it could be confusing you are right, I am going to change this

In Program.cs you need to call
builder.Services.AddControllers();

and then after
var app = builder.Build();

do:
app.MapControllers()

Also to ensure that endpoints to your controller works add Route attribute like this:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetGreeting()
    {
        return Ok("Hello World");
    }
}


Thanks for your anwser, but 1) my Program.cs already has implemented your suggestions and 2) it still doesnt work when I change the Controller.cs. Even if I put a Console.WriteLine into the Constructor of the Controller, it doesn't get printed.

@DaSomes Do you access your controller endpoint like this in Postman: api/HelloWorld/GetGreeting?

yes, and I tried every other possible Route assignment as well. Controller only, Method only, mixed. I just get a 404 Not Found Error. I think the Controller doesn't get recognized by the Program.cs somehow

is error just contains message: "404 Not Found" or it is more verbose? Can you please attach it in your question?

I added screenshots, thats the most verbose I can get I think. So nothing too special I guess

Do your GetGreeting method has an attribute [HttpGet("greet")]? Because if so your endpoint won't work. You should just copy paste my HelloWorldController and check if it works.

And also you told me Console.WriteLine doesn't get printed in Constructor of controller. 1) I checked it with mine HelloWorldController, that i've posted as an answer and 2) I checked with GetGreeting, that has [HttpGet("greet")] attribute. In first case Console.WriteLine got printed, but in second doesn't.

No I tried it with your code, unfortunately it didn't work. Even when I test it on the same machine with localhost:5000, I can successfully curl the /test endpoint, but when I curl the /api/HelloWorld/GetGreeting endpoint I get nothing, no error but no result either.

try to replace app.UseEndpoints() with just app.MapControllers();

Ok finally it works. I can't tell why, I tried the same code as in the question after resetting my network and reinstalling my Debian, somewhere there was an error, but I couldn't find out where it was.
Thank you very much for your effort, especially @Quikler :)

You're welcome :) Yeah, very strange case. Because I'm using Debian 12 Bookworm and it works fine on my machine. I think you skipped something in your code.

I think you can choose my answer as accepted because if someone will have the same problem with the code they will know what to do. Just to not confuse anyone

Jeah maybe I had something messed up in my setup settings bcs that's the only thing I changed, but strange that it affects the connection between the main program and the controller. But jeah in some way you helped me solving my problem, so sure your answer and our conversation fixed it :)
